# Update values in database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have displayed the data in a form `edit.php` and again paas the truk_id in url on update page to `update.php` the data of the fields but it's not working. Can anyone check this

**PHP Code**

```
   <?php
 $truck_id=$_GET['truck_id'];
 print_r($truck_id);
 include("assets/database_con.php");
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
  { 
   $truck_id=$_POST['truck_id'];   
            $truck_number= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['truck_number']));
            $truck_model= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['truck_model']));
            $truck_make= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['truck_make']));
            $truck_type= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['truck_type']));
            $truck_tierweight= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['truck_tierweight']));
            $truck_gvm= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['truck_gvm']));
            $truck_regodate= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['truck_regodate']));
            $truck_inspectaiondate= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['truck_inspectaiondate']));
            $sql1 ="UPDATE add_truck SET truck_number='$truck_number', truck_model='$truck_model', truck_make='$truck_make', truck_type='$truck_type', truck_tierweight='$truck_tierweight', truck_gvm='$truck_gvm', truck_regodate='$truck_regodate', truck_inspectaiondate='$truck_inspectaiondate' where truck_id='$truck_id'";
            echo $sql1;
            $results=$conn->query($sql);
        if($results)
        {
            print 'Success! record updated'; 
        }else{
            print 'no! record updated';
        }                   
    }
?>
```

Comment: whats problem man?

Comment: try echo $sql and execute that sql in phpmyadmin query window and see if the query is correct.

Comment: **WARNING**: Using manual escaping is extremely error prone and a single mistake can lead to a crippling [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning values to fields in single quotes.

The main string is enclosed within single quotes.

Variables inside single quotes are not parsed (value is not calculated).

This is called variable interpolation.

Use double quotes for whole string and single quotes for values.

Corrected SQL:

```
$sql = "UPDATE add_truck 
        SET truck_number='$truck_number', truck_model='$truck_model', 
        truck_make='$truck_make', truck_type='$truck_type', 
        truck_tierweight='$truck_tierweight', 
        truck_gvm='$truck_gvm', truck_regodate='$truck_regodate',
         truck_inspectaiondate='$truck_inspectaiondate' where truck_id='$truck_id'";
```

Comment: print the sql query using: `echo $sql;die();` and post query here.

Answer (score 0):

you are using GET for the truck id and POST for all other variables - is this intentional?

```
$truck_id=$_GET['truck_id'];
```

should it be

```
$truck_id=$_POST['truck_id'];
```

or should all the other variables be from the GET array?

Comment: Using this : 
<?php
 $truck_id=$_GET['truck_id'];
 include("assets/database_con.php");
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
  { 
   $truck_id=$_POST['truck_id'];

Comment: thanks brother for being together ,, I just caught the issues and now fixed.

Comment: no worries - happy to help. good luck with it.click the upvote if my answer helped you at all. Thanks gav

Answer (score 0):

```
$truck_id=$_GET['truck_id'];
```

Here is your problem part you can't get values from get method when you submit. So you need to add some hidden field into your form like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="truck_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['truck_id']; ?>">
```

Change your code like this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
  { 
   $truck_id=$_POST['truck_id']; 
  }
```

I changed your code please look at this

```
//Your code starts now
 <?php
include("header.php");
include("assets/database_con.php");
$truck_id= $_GET['truck_id'];
//print ($truck_id);
?>
<?php
//submit part in top that is better
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$truck_id=$_POST['truck_id'];
$truck_number= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['truck_number']));
$truck_model= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['truck_model']));
$truck_make= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['truck_make']));
$truck_type= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['truck_type']));
$truck_tierweight= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['truck_tierweight']));
$truck_gvm= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['truck_gvm']));
$truck_regodate= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['truck_regodate']));
$truck_inspectaiondate= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['truck_inspectaiondate']));
$sql1 ="UPDATE add_truck SET truck_number='$truck_number', truck_model='$truck_model', truck_make='$truck_make', truck_type='$truck_type', truck_tierweight='$truck_tierweight', truck_gvm='$truck_gvm', truck_regodate='$truck_regodate', truck_inspectaiondate='$truck_inspectaiondate' where truck_id='$truck_id'";
echo $sql1;
die();
$results=$conn->query($sql);
if($results)
{
    print 'Success! record updated';
}else{
    print 'no! record updated';
}
}
?>
```

And changed some thing in here(added action="")

```
 <form role="form" method="post"  action="">
```

And changed some thing in here also(added name="submit")

```
<div class="form-group">

<input type="hidden" name="truck_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['truck_id']; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn_full" id="submit-booking">
</div>
```

No need for another div for hidden because it is 'hidden'

Comment: ok i have checked after echo "$truck_id" vales comes in this page. Let me use your code. thanks..I have checked using this code nth happen ..

Comment: if it helps please let me know

Comment: Should i try this 
<?php
 $truck_id=$_GET['truck_id'];
 print_r($truck_id);
 include("assets/database_con.php");
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
  { 
   $truck_id=$_POST['truck_id'];

Comment: if you want `$_POST['truck_id']` you want some input in your form tag so please add `<input type="hidden" name="truck_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['truck_id']; ?>">` inside your form tag

Comment: otherwise everything perfect

Comment: if it doesn't work echo your query like this `echo $sql;` before  `$results=$conn->query($sql);`

Comment: I have tried all but not reached any solution yet .. Let me move the code in single page ..then check..

Comment: update query not working i think .. nothing happened on submit. I have write the code on view page . Let me share all the code.

I am going to add the code in my Answer . Have a look please.

Comment: `<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn_full" id="submit-booking">`

Comment: Yes i have done have a look plz . if you need I can give you sql after export .

Comment: you are not using name attribute so you will not get `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: please check my new answer

Comment: ssj4sanooj@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

```
Used a new code as solution :
    <?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$truck_id=$_POST['truck_id'];

...
}

and one hidden value with the submit name of attribute :
<input type="hidden" name="truck_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['truck_id']; ?>">
                                   <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn_full" id="submit-booking">
```

Comment: I have tried this .. but no error and nothing happeing in updation.